# How to separate double quoted strings and non double quoted strings using regex?

Tags: regex, go

I'm trying to build a plugin which accepts parameters and each of the parameters can be a double quoted string or a non double quoted string.

Some examples of valid parameters :

1. `"random token"`
2. `"random token" 34`
3. `"randomtoken"`

So I'm trying to write a `parseParameters` function which would return two values, one is the content inside double quoted string and the other is the non double quoted string.

I tried solving this problem with two regular expressions

1. `\"(.*?)\"\s*\d*` - https://regex101.com/r/uB4sI9/145
2. `\"(.*?)\"` - https://regex101.com/r/Pnh9Xd/1

Below is one version of the code I tried (which didn't work for some cases though) :

Variable `parameters` in the below code is going to be a list. Something like ["\"random, "token\"", "45"]

```
    paramString := strings.Join(parameters, " ")
    regex, _ := regexp.Compile(`\"(.*?)\"\s*\d*`)
    tempString := regex.FindString(paramString)
    if len(parameters) == 1 && tempString != "" {
        tempString = strings.TrimLeft(strings.TrimRight(tempString, `\"`), `\"`)
        return tempString, "", true
    }
    if paramString != tempString {
        return "", "", false
    }
    splitBySpace := strings.Split(tempString, " ")
    doubleQuoted := strings.TrimLeft(strings.TrimRight(tempString, `\"`), `\"`)
    nonDoubleQuoted := splitBySpace[len(splitBySpace)-1]
    return doubleQuoted, nonDoubleQuoted, true
```

**Expected input and output**:

**Input** : ["\"random", "token\""]

**Output** : `"random token", ""` (first value specifies the double quoted string while the other value specifies the non double quoted string)

**Input** : ["\"random", "token\"", "45"]

**Output** : ["\"random token\"", 45]

Note that double quotes are escaped in the input.

Comment: Why are you joining the parameters ? Is it not one string ?

It would be good if you can specify your input and expected out put

Comment: So the input I get is a list of strings. So the input for the string `"random token" 45` is going to be a list of strings like ["\"random, "token\"", "45"].

Comment: Updated description with expected input and output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `regex.FindAllStringSubmatch`.

Following function would do the job, the function assumes the input to be a single string like `"random token" 32`

```
func parse(str string) (string, string) {
    regex, _ := regexp.Compile(`("[^"]*")\s*(\S*)`)
    submatches := regex.FindAllStringSubmatch(str, -1)
    if len(submatches) == 0 {
        return "",""
    }
    return submatches[0][1], submatches[0][2]

}
```

You can find working link to a sample program [here](https://play.golang.com/p/TGtYX2Lu63R)